# Detect when jQuery found an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Is there a way to detect when jQuery found in element on the document. For example, I have a function:

```
function filter(jObject) { 
    alert('Did something wonderful');
    console.log(jObject); // jQueryObject
}
```

I want filter to attach itself to every jQuery object and called when $() is triggered. So:

```
<div id="divElement">A Dummy</div>

<script>
    $('#divElement'); // Will trigger filter() and alert will popup.
    // Console will print out the jQuery Object above.
</script>
```

Why I want to do this? Suppose I go

```
document.getElementById('divElement').controller = new function() { ... };
$('#divElement').controller; // This is undefined.
```

Thus i need to write something like $.fn.checkExtendedProperty = function();  and have it triggered each time $ is called to find those property that jQuery misses. (Without modifying jquery.js file itself. I rather not tamper with it for obvious reasons.)

Interesting hack I found, and it works. Not really sure what the implication are yet.

```
$$ = $;
$ = function(mix) {
    var jObj = $$(mix);
    jObj = checkExtendedProperty(jObj); // Binding Extended Property
    return jObj;
};
function checkExtendedProperty(jObj) { ... }
// Copying all References.
for( var i in $$ ) { $[i] = $$[i]; }
```

If anyone know a better way using jQuery native function or some kind of plugin hook, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Just call `filter()` from within a `document.ready` handler, although to be honest this sounds like a very XY question. What exactly do you need to achieve, as this sounds like a needlessly convoluted solution.

Comment: Actually no, you don't ever want to do this "I want filter to attach itself to every jQuery object and called when $() is triggered", unless you want to flood the call stack with an enormous amount of calls to `filter`.

Comment: @gforce301 - actually I do since $() stripped all the custom function to a DOM element. I updated the question for exactly why I want to do it like that.

Comment: @Noobit that makes no sense.

Comment: You can add custom functions to jQuery via it's prototype `$.fn`.

Comment: I want it triggered automatically. like function checkExtendedProperty();

Comment: `$('#divElement')[0].controller()`: https://jsfiddle.net/9vv8a9ce/ Although note that it's a bad idea to add your own properties on to Element objects in the first place.

Comment: Don't do that. Just access the property where it is. Copying it to the jquery object just creates more references for little to no gain. What happens when said jquery object contains more than one element?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the specific issue you're trying to solve really is. My intuition without any details is that the current approach is not great.

Comment: @Noobit You have no idea what you're talking about at all. You can do whatever you want. If jQuery is "stripping" something then you told it to. It doesn't just randomly modify anything. So I'll stand by my statements. "You don't ever want to do this" and "You have no idea what you're talking about".

Comment: jQuery doesn't strip anything, it just wraps the element in an object (jQuery object), to access the raw DOM element use a subscript like (`$(...) [ index ]` or `get` method).

Comment: @gforce301 That could probably be stated in a less-negative way, though.

Comment: @KevinB - my framework is not dependent on jQuery, but I want to extend the control to jQuery just in case for people who uses jQuery to select DOM instead of native way.

Comment: @Noobit you would need implicit iteration for  your methods to be of any use with jquery. You can get that by extending jquery through `$.fn`. you would simply iterate over the collection, calling your method on elements that have it, and skipping those that dont.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution to this problem that makes sense would be to stop adding functions to elements as properties, and create a jQuery method that will interface with your module.

```
// setter/general function call (looks at all selected elements)
$.fn.controller = function (obj) {
  return this.each(function () {
    myModule.controller(this, obj);
  });
};
// getter (only looks at first selected element)
$.fn.getController = function () {
  return myModule.getController(this[0]);
};
```

Instead of adding functions to elements, give them a class that indicate they are associated with your module, and any information you need to be able to identify it with a record in your module should be stored in data attributes.

You could always check to see if jquery is included before defining said methods so that your code will work both with and without jquery.